# Is MVC Framework ill-equipped for rich page design?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just to prefix this question, I've decided to take a look at moving our works old legacy systems (40+ programs from vb6, vba, vb.net to c#.net) into two separate systems using the same DAL (barcoding terminals and one web based system) as I spend most my day fixing crummy or non existant business logic in 15 year old vba programs. I've recently built an entity framework model complete with fluent validation and couldn't be happier with it after using it for a bit.

The small team is familiar with webforms (but not very) but the last few days I've explored MVC Razor.  I was loving MVC Framework until I tried to start trying to add more functions onto the same page and then it seemed arbitrarily hard to replicate our a recent system I put in a webform. Before, I would eager load a customer and all it's child entities and then bind that to single page for the customer so they could access everything (which is what they wanted), it works okay and isn't slow.  From this single page I could edit all their account details/contacts/emails/phones/jobs.

All the examples I've done and seen in MVC handle a single update, a single edit etc but surely you can't separate out every single action into a new view/page? I can pass a rich model through to the view in MVC, but then its a pain trying to update all the different child entities.

This is probably the exact design that MVC wasn't designed for maybe, which is okay, I'm willing to adapt it if MVC will be a better platform going forward, but how are you meant to handle adding this complexity in? Some methods I've seen:

1. Lots of partial views? passing child info to them (or the id and lazy loading it)?
2. I've seen methods that wrap multiple `<forms>` around everything and handle actions that way.
3. Separate pretty much every task out

If the solution is more lightweight and easier to maintain I'll go research whatever I need to I just wanted at an earlier stage to see if I'm wasting my time.  Any pointers to the correct questions I should be asking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably will find yourself making extensive use of partial views and ajax calls in order to achieve the functionality you are describing. While this does tend to have more work/code, it usually lends to better separation and code reuse.

Comment: Yeh I also just recently learnt javascript/jquery + ajax calls and have been using it on another site, so that wouldn't be a problem.  I would just have to prove that all the extra effort would be worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is neither more or less better equipped to deal with complex pages than any other technology out there.

Certainly, MVC requires more low-level work than a Web Forms app, with no direct binding support, but in most cases this is a good thing and provides much more flexibility in how your page is rendered.

One of the whole ideas of MVC is to give you more control over things, but that control leads to requiring more knowledge and more effort on your part in most non-trivial cases.  MVC provides a number of tooling functions to speed up trivial work (like creating standard table based CRUD) but when you have complex models, you will have to do much of the work yourself.

This is not that MVC is "ill suited" for it, but just that control and flexibility has a trade off with more responsibility on your part.

In your case, you simply create a view model with all the fields you want.  Then, you create your form to edit those fields.  In your controller, you will need to unflatten that view model and create or update the necessary records in the database.  It's not difficult, but it's more work than WebForms databinding.

You could look into more advanced tools (commercial) for MVC, such as Telerik's tools, which have developed more of a databinding like interface, but MVC is not a drag-n-drop technology, and requires you to hook things up and write the various logic for what is done.

If you need drag-n-drop, databound functionality, then no.. MVC is not the correct technology.  But then WebForms requires you to accept many compromises as well, and ties your hands in many ways.

You could use partial views, however I seldom use them.  I prefer to instead use Editor/DisplayTemplates as these take care of naming your form fields correctly, even for collections and complex objects.  PartialViews tend to have lots of gotchas if you aren't careful.  I pretty much only use them as fancy includes, or when using Ajax.

I'm not sure what you meay by "wrap multiple `<forms>` around everything`.  You cannot nest forms in HTML, it's not legal.  If you mean place a form around each row of a table, that isn't valid html either in most cases (it's not legal to put a form in a between the table and the tr).

It would help if you had a specific problem that you could ask about, vague objections don't help us solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your post Mystere Man, it wasn't so much of an objection to it, I realise this perception at the minute is due to my lack of knowledge with MVC, I'm actually really loving using Razor in the views and like how clean the markup ends up.  

The <forms> solution was an accepted answer in another post for having multiple buttons on a page for performing different tasks, didn't know if it was a good one or not :)

You definately given me some stuff to look into tomorrow morning

Comment: @PeterLea - There are several ways to support multiple buttons in a page.  The easiest is multiple forms on the page (just don't nest them), and that works really when you want to post to different action methods anyways.  There are also several other methods, including Attibute based methods, as well as simply checking to see which button was pressed by including the property in your parameter lists.  In any event, MVC is very powerful, and most of your concerns about how "suited" it is, are largely because you don't know how to do things in MVC.

Comment: heh, bit of an understatement that, MVC is a big paradigm shift after coming from winforms to webforms. I'll spend the time to learn it all i'm just worried the rest of the team can't be bothered and opt for webforms anyways.

Comment: @PeterLea - I've run into that problem.  Many people "run back" to webforms whenever they have a problem.  Can't blame them really, they have deadlines to meet.  But if you want your team to do MVC then they need to commit to it, and you need to be an expert for them.

Comment: Hi i'm going to mark this as the answer as it seems that with a combination of layouts and Editor/Display templates I can accomplish a lot of what I want to do in a really clean way, so it saved me a lot of time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish anything in MVC that you can in WebForms. The difference is MVC will usually require you to write more code as it doesn't really offer you any "controls" to drop on your page.

In WebForms, it's easy to create a master/detail view with a `GridView`, `FormView` and then wrap everything in an `UpdatePanel` for automagical AJAX support.

In MVC, while you do have helpers like the [`WebGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and [`AjaxHelpers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) extension methods, creating views and/or pages requires more understanding of how things work to get the desired functionality. When I start a new MVC project, here's what I include:

1. [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) - client-side "ORM" that performs CRUD operations
   against RESTful* APIs
2. [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) - client-side view models and
   real-time data-binding for your views
3. [Knockback.js](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/) - wraps
   Backbone models in Knockout view models

Using these three frameworks, you can quickly create powerful single-page apps using MVC and WebAPI.

Comment: Thanks sellmeadog, i'll do some more reading on those libraries tomorrow and see where it gets me.